# Extracting Custom Sql from Tableau using Tableau Rest API

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Is it possible to extract the Custom Sql code from Tableau workbooks using Tableau API?

Has anybody tried it. We need to do it for Code repository and save the code in GIT repo.

Thanks

Comment: Not from the REST but you can from the Metadata API. Here's a good intro into it. https://medium.com/snake-charmer-python-and-analytics/harnessing-the-power-of-tableaus-metadata-api-with-python-a3d536a5ca04

Comment: @Bernardo..Do you have a sample code how achieve it?

Comment: The medium article does. Here's his gist. https://gist.github.com/divinorum-webb/c457916327f1d72ad2750aacdf717d5a